# how to to reuse a docker container between jobs

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have the following code in my gitlab yml:

```
stages:
  - unit_test
  - deploy

Test:
  stage: unit_test
  script:
   - docker run --rm -d --name myimage widgets:0.1 bash -c "tail -f /dev/null"
   - docker exec -w /opt/source-code/tests myimage pwsh -c "dotnet test --test-adapter-path:. --logger:\"junit;LogFilePath=..\TestResults\test-results.xml;MethodFormat=Class;FailureBodyFormat=Verbose\""
   - docker cp myimage:/opt/source-code/TestResults/test-results.xml ./ 
  artifacts:
    when: always
    paths:
      - ./test-results.xml
    reports:
      junit:
        - ./test-results.xml
  tags:
    - docker-azure

deploy_to_dev:
  stage: deploy
  script:
   - docker exec myimage pwsh -c "./mydeploymentscript.ps1"
  only: 
   - master
  tags:
    - docker-azure
```

what the team wants is for a)unit tests to always run whenever the pipeline is triggered but b) the actual deployment logic to only trigger if the branch is master.

The pipeline is currently failing when it gets to the deploy stage with the error:

```
Error: No such container: myimage
```

I was trying to test to see if I could re-use the same container in between jobs since I'm not explicitly doing a "docker stop" on it in the unit test job.  but I guess not.

I know I can repeat all the same commands / do another docker run in the deploy stage, but wondering if there's another way that I just don't know about.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

1. i'm not sure to understand your question. If you want to execute your job when you create a merge request, you can use "rules" like this

```
rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'
```

and the result of your tests will be available in your MR. If you job fail, your pipeline fail and your MR is not merged.

2. For this part, if your job fail, your pipeline fail too.

Comment: sorry I changed my question slightly to be more accurate but +1.  the job does fail if the unit test fails.  thank you

Comment: Hi,
Oh your problem is the image missing. And effectly you just tell that your image is "myimage" but where is this one ? Can you pull this image on your computer ?